# My htc 826 Desire got stuck in bootloop

Tags: boot-loop, htc

the thing is I didn't even try to root or change its recovery, the phone switched off on its own and when I connected the charger it turned on but never went past the HTC logo and keeps rebooting,I have tried a few methods that I found out from a few forums but it doesn't seem to work, why is it still not able to boot properly ?

Answer (score 0):

Update your HTC device, or try to hard rest if nothing happen after trying all your methods. i would say first look to update your HTC Firmware. before updatin firmware make sure you have removed your SIM and SD Card to avoid data lost

Comment: when I try to perform a hard reset it stops real quick during the process and in red letters it shows unable to mount storage